# How to specify default fallback value when empty NLog Property Value

Tags: nlog

I am trying to figure out a way to dump a default value for an property/item when using NLog 5.1.0 under c#/.net6

```
            try
            {
                string loggerName = $"fred";
                string consoleInstanceTarget = $"{loggerName}.console";
                string DEF_LAYOUT = "date=${date} level=${level} myprop=${event-properties:item=myprop} message=${message}";

                LoggingConfiguration nlc = (LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration());

                // console
                ConsoleTarget _consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget { Name = consoleInstanceTarget, Layout = DEF_LAYOUT };
                nlc.AddTarget(_consoleTarget);
                nlc.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule($"{loggerName}", NLog.LogLevel.Info, _consoleTarget));

                NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

                //
                // Grab our new logger to narrow our log focus
                //
                Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
                _logger.Info("my message");
                _logger.WithProperties(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "myprop", "myprop-value" } }).Info("my new message");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine();
            }
```

when I run, no default value dumps for 'myprop'

```
date=2022/12/07 11:48:27.803 level=Info myprop= message=my message
date=2022/12/07 11:48:31.468 level=Info myprop=myprop-value message=my new message
```

I was hoping that event-properties:item=myprop,default='stuff' would have worked.

I've already gone down the route of registering a custom Renderer using

```
NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.Register("myprop", (logEvent, key) => { return "default"; });
```

but it does not get called since the property is embedded in event-properties. If I then update my layout to be simply ${myprop}, then my render function does get called but I then need to always send in the dynamic value to see if it's available based on the event and property key.

Any thoughts for how to specify a default value for ${event-properties}

tia

Comment: I cannot see `event-properties:item=myprop,default='stuff'` in your layout. Have you tried this: `${event-properties:item=myprop:whenEmpty=stuff}`

Comment: Ahh....I knew it had to be something simple. Yes, adding the whenEmpty=  worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NLog provides the `whenEmpty=`-option, that can output fallback-value when LogEvent Property-value is missing or empty.

Example:

```
${event-properties:item=myprop:whenEmpty=stuff}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer